# How to make design content for website?

Tags: website-design

How is content like the one in the link created ? I want to make a flat design website and need to create such images which look cartoonified though flat. How are these created ?

[image: https://dribbble.com/shots/2504282-Dribbble-Green-Hills]

[ [image source](https://dribbble.com/shots/2504282-Dribbble-Green-Hills) ]

Also please mention starting point for learning to create them, a few tuts if you know. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are vector graphics. The shapes are stored as mathematical descriptions that can be rendered onscreen or in print at any size. Conceptually, it is less like drawing with a pencil on paper and more like cutting shapes out of construction paper and gluing them together into a design.

You create vector graphics with a digital pen like a [Wacom](http://www.wacom.com/en-ca) Pen Tablet or [Apple Pencil](http://www.apple.com/apple-pencil/), in combination with software tools like [Adobe Illustrator](http://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator.html) or [Autodesk Graphic](http://graphic.com/) or many others.

Start with YouTube. There are also online courses and books. You have to figure out what tools you want to use. The biggest mistake that beginners make in vector drawing is using a mouse instead of a pen, which is like jogging in skis. Choose a pen first and then choose software to go with the pen. The software is much less important.

[YouTube — Vector Drawing](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=vector%20drawing&page=2)

Comment: Yes but even pixel graphics are stored as mathematical descriptions :) and a mouse works fine.

Comment: The shapes of pixel graphics are not stored as mathematical descriptions except in the way that the entire universe is made of math.

Comment: Another way of looking at is that kneelb4darth's image looks degraded like someone turned the idea of a photograph into oversimplified mathematical descriptions.

Comment: Pixels are matheatical descriptions. Its better to be more explicit and say that vector graphics are made out of objects that describe how the drawings happen. What these objects are is another thing, they could be bitmap images just like in photo editors or they might be curves or something else.

Comment: Of course pixels are stored as mathematical descriptions! And I'm not sure what your thing with tablet/pen is.. theres absolutely nothing wrong with a mouse :) I know people who do incredible illustrations with a mouse and would never touch a tablet.

Comment: @CAI In fact majority of vector graphics is made with mouse. Simply because majority has no pens.

Comment: True. I own a pen and tablet but I still do most of my vector work with either a mouse or trackpad... or keyboard ;)